# Java 3D plot of axis

Tags: java, android, plot, 3d

I am looking for some simple way how to plot on android in 3 dimensions 4 points and 3 lines in real time. I'd like to create a visualization of a coordinate system from arduino setup with 9axis accelerometer, I want to see on the screen how the object rotates.

Something like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOSTOnQzZCI

The values of the points are in a fixed range, do you know some simple library that can be used for this?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this book, it contains all the info you need to create 3D visualizations in Java (including source code that you could use for the visualization you described, with only a small amount of adaptation):

http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP000909.html

This book was my main reference for developing a 3D chart library (Orson Charts) in pure Java (I deliberately did not want to use OpenGL for this project).  I also ported the library to Android (mostly this just involves mapping the Java2D graphics API calls to the equivalent in Android), you can see [the demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.orsoncharts.android.demo&hl=en) on Google Play to get an idea of how the "pure Java" (well, not *really* Java on Android) rendering performs - I'm pretty sure it will handle your task just fine.